# iOS runLoop and openGL

Tags: opengl-es, ios6, nsrunloop

I'm building an iOS application that uses openGL and I have the following problem:

I'have a certain object that I want to show on my glView. If I just draw it once in the view it works just fine. But if I add my drawView function to the runLoop it calls the function perfectly but it doesn't draw anything and I'm just left with a blank white screen.

[Here is all relevant code.](http://pastebin.com/wGJH5mtc)

redraw is a flag that indicates the draw function when to draw the scene again.

I expect the following code to rotate my object each time it's drawn:

```
    static double theta = 0;
    theta += 0.03;
    glRotatef(theta, 1, 1, 0);
```

The rotation works if I don't add the draw function to the runLoop but draw it manually.

Thanks.

Comment: how are you drawing manually?

Comment: I mean that I just call the draw function by myself. It is not called from the runLoop.

Answer (score 0):

The chances are that there is an error in your OpenGL code somewhere.
If everything works in some scenarios it might be context related. Try putting glError calls after and before every OpenGL call. This way you will know where the problematic function is.

You will need to ensure that you set the context to be the correct context for the currently active view.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved!

I just had to add

```
[self setCurrent];
```

to the glView class in the drawView function.